# How to print bold in Python Pyspark in Zeppelin - and other formatting with the python-print-function in Zeppelin

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm using python in Zeppelin on a windows desktop with Zeppelin
installed on a Linux machine and want to print something bold in a
'%pyspark'-cell.

```
print('\033[1m' + 'Hello' + '\033[0m')
```

is working in a Jupyter environment, but in Zeppelin I just get a white
font on white background which is not bold. (I can see that by marking
the text.)

Additionally I may use markdown language. But then I would have to use
separate cells and would not be able to combine the text with python
results.

What else may I try?

Comment: Are you sure that is actually possible?

Comment: No I'm not. But I think it would be useful and many useful things are integrated in Zeppelin. Why do you think that's not possible?

Comment: What I meant by that was, "have you ever seen bold – or any other formatting – in a screenshot of Zeppelin". If you did not, then that would be a pretty clear indication it was not possible – and the reverse, of course. But I see you found an answer, so yay

Comment: @usr2564301 Well, I'm always very optimistic about that. When I think that something makes sense, I also think that it will work somehow. Usually I'm right about that. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Zeppelin you may use html like this to get bold text:

```
print( '%html <b> hello </b>')
```

> **hello**

Just start with "%html" after the first quotation mark, then you may use html syntax until the second quotation mark.

For those who haven't used a lot HTML yet, here are some more **HTML-basics and how they may be used in a %pyspark - Zeppelin cell:**

**other text styles**

```
print('%html <strong>important</strong>')
print('%html <i>italic</i>')
print('%html <del>striked through</del>')
print('%html <sub>low</sub>')
print('%html <sup>high</sup>')
```

for:

> **important** 
>   *italic* 
>   <del>striked through</del> 
>   <sub>low</sub> 
>   <sup>high</sup>

The following does work as well in Zeppelin, I'm just not able to present it right now:

```
print('%html <ins>underlined</ins>')
print('%html <mark>marked</mark>')
print('%html <small>small</small>')
```

You may use h1, h2,...,h6 for **headlines**:

```
print('%html <h1>Heading 1</h1>')
```

> ## Heading 1

**Unordered or ordered lists:**

```
print( '%html <ul>  <li>something</li>  <li>anything</li> </ul>  ')
print( '%html <ol>  <li>first</li>  <li>second</li> </ol>  ')
```

> - something
> - anything
>
> 1. first
> 2. second

**Links:**

```
 print('%html print <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">This is a link to stackoverflow.com</a> ')
```

> [This is a link to stackoverflow.com](https://www.stackoverflow.com)

**Abreviations or info texts that appear when you move the mouse over the original word.**

```
print('%html <p><abbr title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr> is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications.</p>')
```

You may try it in Zeppelin.

**Text colors**

e.g. based on rgb color space where r,g,b is the amount of red, green and blue in your color:

```
print('%html <p style="color:rgb(255, 0, 0);">red</p>')
print('%html <p style="color:rgb(0, 255, 0);">green</p>')
print('%html <p style="color:rgb(0, 0, 255);">blue</p>')
```

[Some examples for color codes](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html)

You may color the background as well:

```
print('%html <p style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);">Background is red</p>')
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!